# onActivityResult not getting called when calling java activity from kotlin for result

Tags: android, kotlin, startactivityforresult

I am using Kotlin and Java in my project. I am opening a Java activity for result from Kotlin but the `onActivityResult` function written in Kotlin never gets called.

Code (Kotlin):

```
 override fun viewAllNotes() {
        val intent : Intent = Intent(this, ViewAllNotesActivity::class.java)
        intent.putExtra(AppConstants.VIEW_ALL_FLOW, AppConstants.VIEW_ALL_NOTES_FLOW)
        startActivityForResult(intent, VIEW_ALL_REQUEST_CODE)
 }


override fun onActivityResult(requestCode: Int, resultCode: Int, data: Intent?) {
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data)
    if (resultCode == Activity.RESULT_OK){
        if (requestCode == VIEW_ALL_REQUEST_CODE){
            if (data!!.getParcelableArrayListExtra<ListNote>(AppConstants.NOTES_LIST)!=null){
                mViewModel.mNotesReminders.listNote = data.getParcelableArrayListExtra(AppConstants.NOTES_LIST)
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Code (Java):

```
 @Override
 public void onBackPressed() {
        Intent result = new Intent();
        result.putParcelableArrayListExtra(AppConstants.NOTES_LIST, mNotesList);
        setResult(Activity.RESULT_OK, result);
        this.finish();
 }
```

logcat

```
09-19 23:13:18.343 1552-1843/? I/ActivityManager: START u0 {cmp=com.raj.ifa.debug/com.raj.ifa.ui.viewAllNotesAndReminder.ViewAllNotesActivity (has extras)} from uid 10081 on display 0
09-19 23:13:18.383 28407-28407/com.raj.ifa.debug I/AppCompatViewInflater: app:theme is now deprecated. Please move to using android:theme instead.
09-19 23:13:18.607 28407-28412/com.raj.ifa.debug I/art: Do partial code cache collection, code=124KB, data=100KB
09-19 23:13:18.619 28407-28412/com.raj.ifa.debug I/art: After code cache collection, code=123KB, data=100KB
09-19 23:13:18.619 28407-28412/com.raj.ifa.debug I/art: Increasing code cache capacity to 512KB
09-19 23:13:18.792 28407-28428/com.raj.ifa.debug D/EGL_emulation: eglMakeCurrent: 0xa89852a0: ver 2 0 (tinfo 0xa8983630)
09-19 23:13:18.823 28407-28428/com.raj.ifa.debug D/EGL_emulation: eglMakeCurrent: 0xa89852a0: ver 2 0 (tinfo 0xa8983630)
09-19 23:13:18.858 1552-1572/? I/ActivityManager: Displayed com.raj.ifa.debug/com.raj.ifa.ui.viewAllNotesAndReminder.ViewAllNotesActivity: +500ms
09-19 23:13:18.863 28407-28428/com.raj.ifa.debug D/EGL_emulation: eglMakeCurrent: 0xa89852a0: ver 2 0 (tinfo 0xa8983630)
09-19 23:13:18.880 28407-28428/com.raj.ifa.debug D/EGL_emulation: eglMakeCurrent: 0xa89852a0: ver 2 0 (tinfo 0xa8983630)
09-19 23:13:18.925 28407-28407/com.raj.ifa.debug W/IInputConnectionWrapper: finishComposingText on inactive InputConnection
09-19 23:13:18.950 28407-28428/com.raj.ifa.debug D/EGL_emulation: eglMakeCurrent: 0xa89852a0: ver 2 0 (tinfo 0xa8983630)
09-19 23:13:18.953 28407-28428/com.raj.ifa.debug D/OpenGLRenderer: endAllActiveAnimators on 0x8e89d080 (RippleDrawable) with handle 0x8e85d6c0
09-19 23:13:19.240 1552-22693/? I/WindowManager: Destroying surface Surface(name=com.raj.ifa.debug/com.raj.ifa.ui.userDetails.UserDetailsActivity) called by com.android.server.wm.WindowStateAnimator.destroySurface:2014 com.android.server.wm.WindowStateAnimator.destroySurfaceLocked:881 com.android.server.wm.WindowState.destroyOrSaveSurface:2073 com.android.server.wm.WindowManagerService.tryStartExitingAnimation:3017 com.android.server.wm.WindowManagerService.relayoutWindow:2897 com.android.server.wm.Session.relayout:215 android.view.IWindowSession$Stub.onTransact:286 com.android.server.wm.Session.onTransact:136 
09-19 23:13:21.707 28407-28428/com.raj.ifa.debug D/EGL_emulation: eglMakeCurrent: 0xa89852a0: ver 2 0 (tinfo 0xa8983630)
09-19 23:13:21.767 28407-28428/com.raj.ifa.debug D/EGL_emulation: eglMakeCurrent: 0xa89852a0: ver 2 0 (tinfo 0xa8983630)
09-19 23:13:21.800 28407-28428/com.raj.ifa.debug D/EGL_emulation: eglMakeCurrent: 0xa89852a0: ver 2 0 (tinfo 0xa8983630)
09-19 23:13:21.831 28407-28428/com.raj.ifa.debug D/EGL_emulation: eglMakeCurrent: 0xa89852a0: ver 2 0 (tinfo 0xa8983630)
09-19 23:13:21.834 28407-28428/com.raj.ifa.debug D/OpenGLRenderer: endAllActiveAnimators on 0x8ce94e80 (RippleDrawable) with handle 0x8e85d270
09-19 23:13:22.084 1552-14164/? I/WindowManager: Destroying surface Surface(name=com.raj.ifa.debug/com.raj.ifa.ui.viewAllNotesAndReminder.ViewAllNotesActivity) called by com.android.server.wm.WindowStateAnimator.destroySurface:2014 com.android.server.wm.WindowStateAnimator.destroySurfaceLocked:881 com.android.server.wm.WindowState.removeLocked:1449 com.android.server.wm.WindowManagerService.removeWindowInnerLocked:2478 com.android.server.wm.WindowManagerService.removeWindowLocked:2436 com.android.server.wm.WindowManagerService.removeWindowLocked:2305 com.android.server.wm.WindowManagerService.removeWindow:2300 com.android.server.wm.Session.remove:193 
09-19 23:13:22.261 28407-28428/com.raj.ifa.debug D/EGL_emulation: eglMakeCurrent: 0xa89852a0: ver 2 0 (tinfo 0xa8983630)
```

Can anyone tell me what is wrong with my above code?

Comment: Whats in the `logcat`?

Comment: @CodyCaughlan I have updated the queston

Comment: are there any fragments involved or is it activity to activity?

Comment: @buradd it is activity to activity

Comment: try putting a break point on the line super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data), then debug it and see if the super is getting called at all.. if it's getting called and just not hitting your result_code condition than we can narrow down the cause better

Comment: When `viewAllNotes` is called?

Comment: When ```onActivityResult``` is called. First line ```super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data)```. A breakpoint there.

Comment: You should probably override finish() instead of onbackpressed() so it will also set the result if you press the up button (which is different from the back button)

Comment: The result is being set for sure. I have debugged the code and it is reaching the last line but after that there is no callback received in onActivityResult

Comment: @RajSuvariya did u found the solution?

Comment: @Mahesh yes I solved it. There was no issue with code something wrong with the build. I refreshed the gradle and it worked